# Filling gaps in raster to zero value cells?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, spatial-analyst

I am trying to add some forest elevations to a DEM using an ArcView (Basic) level license of ArcGIS Desktop.  I have converted a polygon feature class of a forest into a raster with the same resolution as my DEM.  Then I reclassed the forest raster to 15 (the height of the forest).  This has resulted in a patchy raster with gaps of nothing between.

To get a raster that covers the entire study area I created a constant raster with the extent of the forest polygon and containing the value of 0.  when I add the two rasters together I end up with a replica of my forest raster rather than a raster with forest cells of value 15 and 0 values everywhere else.

Any Ideas of how to fill in the gaps between my forest cells?

Comment: When you use the Identify tool on those gaps what value is returned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that your "gaps" are, in fact, NoData. The rule in raster operators is that NoData begets NoData. You can use the raster calculator and a nested statement, without the use of the constant raster, to set NoData to 0. Depending on the version of ArcMap you may need to play with syntax but the basic idea is:

```
Con(IsNull("raster"), 0, "raster")
```

This states that if the raster is NoData then assign the new raster 0 else keep the value of the original raster.

Comment: for an extensive description of the magic formula above see [Working with Digital Elevation Models, Patching Gaps](http://www.quantdec.com/SYSEN597/GTKAV/section9/chapter_29d.htm#patching) by our own @whuber and [Assembling DEM Files for Watershed Analysis](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0701/moredem.html)